# How to extend a partial order on a finite set

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set and let $\le$ be a partial order order on the set $A$.

Suppose that $a,b \in A$ are two elements of $A$ such that $a \not \le b$ and $b \not \le a$.

I define a new binary relation $T$ on the set $A$ setting $T := \{(x,y) \in A \times A \mid x \le a \text{ and } b \le y\}$.

I define another new binary relation $\le^*$ on the set $A$ setting $\le^*=\le \cup T$.

I claim that $\le^*$ is a partial order on the set $A$, that $\le^*$ extends $\le$ and that $a \le^* b$.

I have that $(a,b) \in T \subseteq \le^*$, that is, $a \le^* b$.

I have that $\le \subseteq \le^*$.

I have that $\le \subseteq \le^*$ and that $\le$ is reflexive, so $\le^*$ is reflexive.

But how can I prove that $\le^*$ is antisymmetric and transitive?

Comment: You claim that $\leq^*$ that is a partial order based on what?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker That was the question.

Comment: @AnneBauval I read the other question, but how can I prove that $\le^*$ is antisymmetric?

Comment: It is very easy. Have a try!

Comment: Suppose that $p\le^*q$ and $q\le^*p$, I have to show that $p=q$. There are four cases: ($p\leq$ and $q\le p$) or ($p\leq$ and $qTp$) or ($pTq$ and $q\le p$) or ($pTq$ and $qTp$). The first case is easy: if $p\leq$ and $q\le p$ then $p=q$ because $\le$ is antisymmetric. But how can I prove the other cases?

Answer (score 1):

I try to prove that $\le^*$ is antisymmetric.

I have to prove that if $p \le^* q$ and $q \le^* p$ then $p=q$.

There are four cases: ($p \le q$ and $q \le p$) or ($p \le q$ and $qTp$) or ($pTq$ and $q \le p$) or ($pTq$ and $qTp$).

Case 1: $p \le q$ and $q \le p$. If $p \le q$ and $q \le p$ then $p=q$ because $\le$ is a partial order (in particular $\le$ is antisymmetric).

Case 2: $p \le q$ and $qTp$. If $p \le q$ and $qTp$ then $p \le q$, $q \le a$ and $b \le p$, then $b \le a$ because $\le$ is a partial order (in particular $\le$ is transitive), this is a contraddiction because $b \not \le a$ by hypothesis. So case 2 is impossible.

Case 3: $pTq$ and $q \le p$. If $pTq$ and $q \le p$ then $p \le a$, $b \le q$ and $q \le p$, then $b \le a$ because $\le$ is a partial order (in particular $\le$ is transitive), this is a contraddiction because $b \not \le a$ by hypothesis. So case 3 is impossible.

Case 4: $pTq$ and $qTp$. If $pTq$ and $qTp$ then $p \le a$, $b \le q$, $q \le a$ and $b \le p$, then $b \le a$ because $\le$ is a partial order (in particular $\le$ is transitive), this is a contraddiction because $b \not \le a$ by hypothesis. So case 4 is impossible.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: (+1) Yes, it is.